# Trying to change a row of a user filled table with jquery only works on first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i'm working on a school assignment where i have a couple of forms which then through a jquery function fill a table with data. The forms are filled in by the user. One of the tasks is also to make it possible for the user to click on a row in the table, which changes its color to red and then through the push of a button at the bottom of the table deletes the colored row(s).

I cannot seem to do so (change a rows color). I can only change the color of the first row (the one that contains the  tags), all the other rows don't respond uppon clicking on them. I don't know if this is due to the fact that the first row is written in the .html file and the other rows are created afterwards with jquery, but I can't seem to get it up and running.

Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <p>
    Naslov opravila: <input id="naslov" type="text" name="naslov">
    Vrsta opravila: <input id="vrsta" type="text" name="vrsta">
    Nivo pomembnosti: 
    <select name="nivo" class="nivo">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <button class="button">Dodaj opravilo</button>
    </form>
    </p>
    <table class="tabela" cellspacing="3" style="text-align:center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Opravilo</th>
                <th>Vrsta</th>
                <th>Nujnost</th>
                <th>Datum vnosa</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="telo">
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button id="odstrani">Odstrani</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here's the .js code:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(event) {
    var naslov = $('#naslov').val();
    var vrsta = $('#vrsta').val();
    var nivo = $('.nivo option:selected').val();
    var vrste = $('#telo').find('tr').length;
    var datum = new Date();
    var d = datum.getDate() + "." + (datum.getMonth()+1) + "." + datum.getFullYear();
    if(naslov.length > 0) {
        var novavrsta = $('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
        novavrsta.children().eq(0).text(vrste+1);
        novavrsta.children().eq(1).text(naslov);
        novavrsta.children().eq(2).text(vrsta);
        novavrsta.children().eq(3).text(nivo);
        novavrsta.children().eq(4).text(d);
        novavrsta.appendTo('#telo');
        $( "#telo tr" ).addClass(function( index ) {
            return "vrsta" + (index+1);
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).css({"color":"red"});
    $(this).addClass("izbrano");
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you possibly set up a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: yes ofcourse, her it is: http://jsfiddle.net/s5xUD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your elements are dynamically created you should use .on()

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"red"});
    $(this).addClass("izbrano");
});
```

Also if you don't want to change the table header use the selector:

```
'tbody tr'
```